# Non responsive layout using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to use flexbox to design non responsive layout.could you provide example of such layout.[image]

This is the layout I have been trying to build as non responsive using flexbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a static width on the container.

Updated Example based on comments below:

CSS Changed to:

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/zycrr08n/8/

Comment: Could you provide example @developernator

Comment: Show me what you have so far and I can tell you what the issue is.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flexline

Comment: thanks for the image but I meant the the code sample

Comment: but the red rectangle is not occupying full screen https://jsfiddle.net/jeremykenedy/zycrr08n/7/show/ and it has white space isssue at bottom when viewed in large screen i still couldnt figure out how to get rectangles on right side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125259/discussion-between-user93-and-developernator).

Comment: There is a static width on that of 500px

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using flexbox if you don't want a responsive layout? Use static width divs and potentially some positioning properties to set up the layout how you want.

Comment: because alignment using flexbox seems really simple than others